# How to bind data from View to ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I have little knowledge about mvvm, but this is how I wrote my code this far:

```
<Image x:Name ="new_tooltip" Grid.Row="84" Grid.Column="57" Grid.ColumnSpan="78"  Grid.RowSpan="15"  Source="/MS_Show_Assets/MainMenuAssets/TT-Startscreen-MainMenu-New-DE.png" Visibility = "{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=New, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsNewTooltipVisible, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

and ViewModel:

```
public class ViewMainMenuViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public string IsNewTooltipVisible { get; set; }

        public ViewMainMenuViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
```

So basically, I want some image in the view to become visible if the mouse is over some button. Then once this image is visible, I want to send "Visible" to a property that is in ViewModel class. What else am I missing in this class?

Comment: Don't send  "Visible" to the viewmodel, if you do then you are breaking one of the fundamental rules of MVVM (separation between view and viewmodel).

Comment: Yes, I know...I should send it as a boolean or string, and I know I should use visibilitytoboolean converter....

Comment: Tried binding `IsMouseOver` using `OneWayToSource`? I think this was impossible in previous .NET versions, maybe it isn't any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need a property in VM to do this. You can use Trigger on View itself to show/hide image on button mouseover as below. Here ElementName is the name of the button whose mouseover you want to capture.

```
<Image x:Name ="new_tooltip" Grid.Row="84" Grid.Column="57" Grid.ColumnSpan="78"  Grid.RowSpan="15"  Source="/MS_Show_Assets/MainMenuAssets/TT-Startscreen-MainMenu-New-DE.png" Visibility = "{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=New, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=myButton}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason why I want to send it to the property in the ViewModel is beacuse I have another View (XAML) in which something also need to change on mouse over button in first view. So this is why I wanted to store it in the property and then pass it further to other viewmodel or something....